# How do you re-render Flatlist when value of dropdown list changes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo, react-native-flatlist

I am fetching an array from the database in Componentdidmount in the state variable this.state.dataSource

```
componentDidMount(){

    fetch("http://docbook.orgfree.com/home.php", {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "auth-token": "my token",
      },
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
        this.setState({
          isLoading: false,
          dataSource: responseJson, 

        });
        if (responseJson) {
          Alert.alert("Id is" + JSON.stringify(responseJson)); 
        // this.state.dataSource = this.state.dataSource.filter(x => x.Tag === this.state.text);
        // console.log(this.state.dataSource[0])
         
        } else if (responseJson.error) {
          Alert.alert(responseJson.error);
        }
      })

      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });

    
}
```

this.state.Datasource contains an array like:

[
{
description:"kjs",
tag:"beach",
name:"nkslk",
place:"kdlk",
image:"kgmls"
},
{
description:"knsldk",
tag:"club",
name:"nklf",
place:"dlk",
image:"nkxn"
},
]

I have a dropdown list that contains value of different tags in my database like
beach,club,temple,fort,etc

I want to render only those items in my flat list whose tag matches with the tag in my array and when the dropdown value changes I want to re-render my flatlist to the Array elements which has the new tag

My complete source code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Dropdown } from 'react-native-material-dropdown';
import { Button, View, Text, StyleSheet, Image ,Alert,FlatList} from "react- 
native";
class explore extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
       super(props);
        this.state = {
        tag: '',
       isLoading:true,
       dataSource:[]
    };
}

componentDidMount(){

    fetch("http://docbook.orgfree.com/home.php", {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "auth-token": "my token",
      },
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
        this.setState({
          isLoading: false,
          dataSource: responseJson, 

        });
        if (responseJson) {
          // Alert.alert("Id is" + JSON.stringify(responseJson)); 
          console.log(this.state.dataSource)
         
        } else if (responseJson.error) {
          // Alert.alert(responseJson.error);
        }
      })

      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });

    
}

render() {
    const { dataSource, tag } = this.state;

    const tagFilter = item => {
          if (tag) {
            return item.tag === tag;
          }
          return true;
    }
    let data = [{
      value: 'Church',
    }, {
      value: 'Beach',
    }, {
      value: 'Temple',
    },{
      value:'Waterfall' 
    },
    {
      value:'Town'
    }];
    
return (    
      <View>
        <Dropdown
            label='TAG'
            data={data}
            onChangeText={tag => this.setState({ tag })}
        />
        <FlatList
          data={dataSource.filter(tagFilter)}
          ItemSeparatorComponent={this.FlatListItemSeparator}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <View >
              <Text >{item.name}</Text>
              <Text >#{item.Tag}</Text>

             
            </View>
          )}
          keyExatractor={({ name }) => name}
        />


      </View>

);
}
}
export default explore;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the tags to filter by in state and simple filter your data source inline versus in the onChange callback of the dropdown component. The following destructures `tag` and `dataSource` from state, and defines a filter function to be used as array::filter callback. If `tag` is truthy then apply filter if tags match, otherwise return true to allow item to be passed through, i.e. unfiltered.

```
this.state = {
  text: 'Temple',
  isLoading: true,
  dataSource: [], // <-- provide defined initial state
  tag: '', // <-- tag
};

...

render() {
  let data = [{
      value: 'Church',
    }, {
      value: 'Beach',
    }, {
      value: 'Temple',
  }];

  const { dataSource, tag } = this.state; // <-- destructure

  const tagFilter = item => { // <-- filter callback
    if (tag) {
      return item.tag.toLowerCase() === tag.toLowerCase(); // <-- compare using lowercase!
    }
    return true;
  }

  return (    
    <View>
      <Dropdown
        label='TAG'
        data={data}
        onChangeText={tag => this.setState({ tag })} // <-- save tag to state
      />
      <FlatList
        data={dataSource.filter(tagFilter)} // <-- filter data
        ItemSeparatorComponent={this.FlatListItemSeparator}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <View >
            <Text >{item.name}</Text>
            <Text >#{item.Tag}</Text>
          </View>
        )}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: TypeError:undefined is not an object (evaluating dataSource.filter)

Comment: @Akashkunwar Did you destructure `dataSource` from the state object? I'll update answer so it is a little clearer where the changes go.

Comment: @Akashkunwar Updated. An additional note, since the underlaying data is changing and `FlatList` uses index by default if the data doesn't have a `key` property or you don't specify [keyExtractor](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#keyextractor) you may have rendering issues, just a warning. Hopefully this is a little clearer.

Comment: I have updated my code as per the changes made by you but still, I am getting TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating dataSource.filter) and I don't think there are any rendering issues because  it is rendering fine in a different activity .

Comment: I have updated my question also if you can look at the updated code it will be really helpful

Comment: @Akashkunwar Oh, looks like you just need some default initial state, i.e. `dataSource: []`. `dataSource` is undefined when the component first mounts.

Comment: @Akashkunwar If you have a field/property in each item that you know is unique within the dataset, like `name`, then that is a good candidate. `keyExatractor={({ name }) => name}`. If you don't have that guarantee then I suggest using some guid (uuid/v4 is a good one) to assign a `key` property to each element in `dataSource` when it's fetched. Add this property before saving into state.

Comment: Okay so I have updated the code again added keyExtractor but when I am updating the dropdown value nothing is rendering

Comment: @Akashkunwar It was silly error, your "tag" options are Titlecase, but your "tag" properties are lowercase. Just make sure they have the same casing when comparing tags. https://snack.expo.io/@drew.w.reese/filter-a-flatlist-by-dropdown-value